# Docusign Soap API returns Unspecified Error

Tags: soap, salesforce, docusignapi

I have been trying to send a docusign envelope from Salesforce using the docusign SOAP API. I am using the CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates method of the Docusign API, I have a functional template created in my docusign sandbox, but everytime I send the request I get an Unspecified Error in my response. Below is the code the I am using

```
wwwDocusignNetApi30.EnvelopeInformation envelope = new wwwDocusignNetApi30.EnvelopeInformation();
envelope.Subject = 'Envelope Subject' ;     
envelope.EmailBlurb = 'Email Blurb';
envelope.AccountId = '********-****-****-****-************';

//use custom field to store the id of the record that initiated the transaction    
envelope.CustomFields = new wwwDocusignNetApi30.ArrayOfCustomField();
envelope.CustomFields.CustomField = new wwwDocusignNetApi30.CustomField[2];
wwwDocusignNetApi30.CustomField myCustomField = new wwwDocusignNetApi30.CustomField();
myCustomField.Name = 'DSFSSourceObjectId'; 
myCustomField.Value = '0012600000PQn9g'; 
myCustomField.Show = 'false';
myCustomField.Required = 'false';
myCustomField.CustomFieldType = 'Text';
envelope.CustomFields.CustomField.add(myCustomField);

wwwDocusignNetApi30.ArrayOfTemplateReference templateArray = new wwwDocusignNetApi30.ArrayOfTemplateReference();
templateArray.TemplateReference = new wwwDocusignNetApi30.TemplateReference[2];
wwwDocusignNetApi30.TemplateReference templat = new wwwDocusignNetApi30.TemplateReference();// TemplateReferences 
templat.Template = '********-****-****-****-************';
templat.TemplateLocation = 'Server';

wwwDocusignNetApi30.ArrayOfRecipient1 recArray = new wwwDocusignNetApi30.ArrayOfRecipient1();
recArray.Recipient = new wwwDocusignNetApi30.Recipient[2];
wwwDocusignNetApi30.Recipient recipient = new wwwDocusignNetApi30.Recipient();
recipient.ID = 100987;
recipient.Type_x = 'Signer';
recipient.RoutingOrder = 2;
recipient.Email = 'example@example.com';
recipient.UserName = 'Test';
recArray.Recipient.add(recipient);

wwwDocusignNetApi30.TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment trra = new wwwDocusignNetApi30.TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment();
trra.RoleName='Signer 1';
trra.RecipientID = recipient.ID;

wwwDocusignNetApi30.ArrayOfTemplateReferenceRoleAssignment roleArray = new wwwDocusignNetApi30.ArrayOfTemplateReferenceRoleAssignment();
roleArray.RoleAssignment = new wwwDocusignNetApi30.TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment[1];
roleArray.RoleAssignment.add(trra);

templat.RoleAssignments = new wwwDocusignNetApi30.ArrayOfTemplateReferenceRoleAssignment();
templat.RoleAssignments = (roleArray);
templateArray.TemplateReference.add(templat);

String auth = '<DocuSignCredentials><Username>********-****-****-****-************</Username><Password>PASSWORD</Password><IntegratorKey>********-****-****-****-************</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>';
wwwDocusignNetApi30.APIServiceSoap service = new wwwDocusignNetApi30.APIServiceSoap();
service.inputHttpHeaders_x =  new Map<String, String>();
service.inputHttpHeaders_x.put('X-DocuSign-Authentication',auth);
service.CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates(templateArray,recArray,envelope,true);
```

Below is the response I receive:

```
System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: Unspecified_Error faultcode=soap:Server faultactor=https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx
```

Since the error message is vague, I am not able to debug the issue. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you start with a simpler request.  Look at the recipes on github.com/docusign that start with sfdc

Get the simpler request working, then add features to get it to your needs.

One thing I did notice was that you are not giving a routing order of 1 to your only recipient. But that's probably OK.

I'm not sure that your template reference is correct since you should not be using composite templates for a simple template reference.  Unfortunately I don't have a lot of experience with the soap api. HTH.

Comment: I have been able to rectify the Unspecified error, instead of using the SOAP API, I am directly sending the SOAP xml to docusign and adding soap headers in the xml solved the unspecified error. But now I am getting "This Account lacks sufficient permissions." error now.  Any idea why this can happen. I have seen a few answers by @Ergin, wherein he has mentioned that docusign support can help. I have tried contacting them, but they say all permissions are enabled on my dev sandbox.

Comment: I'm glad that it is working! Please post a new question, and *include your request / response.* (But remove your integration key and any other private information.) @AsifBhat